# cannot write to inventory in python

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code I made for an inventory for my game:

```
def getInv(user):
file = "%s.inv" % user
dir = "inventories/"
fp = "%s%s" % (dir,file)
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
if not os.path.isfile(fp):
    bag = open(fp, "w")
    bag.write("NULL\n")
    bag.close()

bag = open(fp, "r")
baglines = bag.readlines()
bag.close()

bag = []

for line in baglines:
    bag.append(line.replace("\n",""))

if "NULL" in bag:
    del bag[bag.index("NULL")]

if len(bag) != 0:        
    return bag
else:
    return ["empty"]
```

..So that's that. The problem that i'm having is that i'm not able to write to hardfile. For example, if I manually write in something in a specific user's inventory file, it will show up when I call the method for their inventory. However, I cannot seem to use the 'giveItem' method to add to the inventory and I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
def giveItem(user, item):
item = str(item)
file = "%s.inv" % user
dir = "inventories"
fp = "%s%s" % (dir,file)
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
if not os.path.isfile(fp):
    bag = open(fp, "w")
    bag.write("NULL\n")
    bag.close()

bag = open(fp, "a")
bag.write(item+'\n')
bag.close()
```

Comment: I realize I screwed the indents up when I pasted the code, please ignore it.

Comment: Indentation is *crucial* in Python, we can't *"ignore it"*. Please read http://StackOverflow.com/help/mcve, then when you have a minimal example paste it in, select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fp` variable in `giveItems` doesn't include a slash, so for a user named, say, `"Arman"`, it'll write to `"inventoriesArman.inv"` in the current directory, rather than `"Arman.inv"` in the `"inventories"` folder, which is where `getInv` will look.

Rather than using string formatting to build the full path by hand, I suggest using `os.path.join` which is designed for exactly this purpose: `fp = os.path.join(dir, file)`.